# Resize Panel Size On Windows Form Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have 2 panels on windows form and both occupied the equal portion on form (i.e. 50%- 50%). Once i run the application, I want to resize the panel size by dragging form with mouse (i.e. 25%-75%). The portion given is not fixed it can be in any size. I just want to resize the panel by dragging/streching mouse.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Soorajbhan kuntal

Comment: Do you mean that, when resizing the Form of, say, 1 pixels, suddenly one Panel occupies the 25% of the Form client area and the other one 75% of it? Have you tried the FlowLayoutPanel or the TableLayoutPanel, to see whether you can set them up the way you want? Also, try to provide a more precise description of the layout you want and how it behaves when the Form is resized in different manners.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a [`SplitContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/splitcontainer-control-windows-forms) control on your form. Put the `Panel` controls into the two different containers of the `SplitContainer`, and set their `Dock` property to `Fill`. You can set the `SplitContainer` to `Dock.Fill` too or set the `Anchor` properties such that the `SplitContainer` stretches along with the form.

Comment: Thanks! Dave. Your opinion seems to valid and i will give a try.